# Add item to Mysql table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a item to a table in Mysql that doesn't make multiples of the same guid, but it just keeps adding multiples, even tho I use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$guid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, htmlspecialchars($_GET['guid'])); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (guid) VALUES ('$guid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE guid='$guid'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to add a item to a table in Mysql that doesn't make multiples of the same guid, but it just keeps adding multiples, even tho I use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

If it keeps on adding Duplicates then your Key is not really a key as you believe. You do not have a primary/unique constraint on guid, hence no duplication trigger.

If `guid` had that constraint then even with an incorrect logic mysql would not allow you to add duplicate values. Fix that and your query will work as expected.

Comment: So how do I add this constraint to guid?

Comment: Make `guid` a primary key or add a `unique` index to it

Comment: Thanks :)
PRIMARY KEY (`guid`)